# Send commands to Google Chrome's Developer Console through cmd etc

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to create a program that can pause videos on youtube using the media-keys on my keyboard.

What I found was that in the development-console I can use `$('#movie_player').pauseVideo();` to pause and playVideo to resume playback.

But that's still in chrome. Is there someway I can send that command to the development-console with another program?